# np.uint8() makes the normal vectors are wrongly calculated

Tags: python, graphics, normals

So, I wanted to calculate normal vectors of edges by applying gradients to the depth image. When I changed my matrix image with np.uint8() for some reason (#1st try), the normals are heading to the wrong directions as shown in the picture below. In the normals function, I used ndimage.sobel to calculate the gradients. 
[Wrong Normal Vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wViEp.png)

When I changed the input image from the real matrix that I generated (#2nd Try), the normal vectors are calculated correctly as shown in the picture. Can someone explain why is this like this? 
[Correct Normal Vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs9Zh.png)

```
#1st try
sm_im = np.zeros((100,100))
sm_im[30:-30, 20:-20] = 1
sm_im = nd.rotate(sm_im, 25, mode='constant')
sm_im_copy = np.uint8(sm_im) #HERE IS THE np.uint8
sm_edge_im = cv2.Canny(sm_im_copy, 1, 5)
normals_pm, edge_pm = normals(sm_im_copy, sm_edge_im) #PAY ATTENTION HERE
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Adam Syammas Zaki P\Documents\Assignment\Grasp Planning\Simulation\Image\simple_debug_edge.png', sm_edge_im)
save_arr = r'C:\Users\Adam Syammas Zaki P\Documents\Assignment\Grasp Planning\Simulation\Image\sm_normal_debug.png'
depth = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Adam Syammas Zaki P\Documents\Assignment\Grasp Planning\Simulation\Image\simple.png')
draw_normals(edge_pm, normals_pm, depth, save_arr)

#2nd try
sm_im = np.zeros((100,100))
sm_im[30:-30, 20:-20] = 1
sm_im = nd.rotate(sm_im, 25, mode='constant') #USING THE ORIGINAL MATRIX
sm_im_copy = np.uint8(sm_im)
sm_edge_im = cv2.Canny(sm_im_copy, 1, 5)
normals_pm, edge_pm = normals(sm_im, sm_edge_im) #PAY ATTENTION HERE
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Adam Syammas Zaki P\Documents\Assignment\Grasp Planning\Simulation\Image\simple_debug_edge.png', sm_edge_im)
save_arr = r'C:\Users\Adam Syammas Zaki P\Documents\Assignment\Grasp Planning\Simulation\Image\sm_normal_debug.png'
depth = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Adam Syammas Zaki P\Documents\Assignment\Grasp Planning\Simulation\Image\simple.png')
draw_normals(edge_pm, normals_pm, depth, save_arr)
```

Comment: Your original data has `dtype('float64')` with `max = 1.13` and `min = -0.11`. So converting to `dtype('uint8')` gives dramatic precision drop. For details, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.